# How to use ItemsControl inside SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView in UWP?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I currently have used a `SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView` which contains a `ListView` but I would like to use `ItemsConrol` instead of `ListView` for various reasons major one being that `ItemsControl` come with variable height rows depending on the data inside, unlike `ListView` which has fixed row height.

But I was not able to use `ItemsControl` since `SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView` takes only `ListViewBase` type elements. So what are my other options.

Comment: I used a default `ListView` and put 4 different sizes of `Rectangle`s as 4 items, you can see the [rendering image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAnD7.gif), so "unlike ListView which has fixed row height." What did you mean then?

Comment: But I have to know the size of rows before hand right? Cause what if I need text content and the size of each row be equal to content.

Comment: I wrote an answer to explain this behavior, if you still have question, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I have to know the size of rows before hand right? Cause what if I need text content and the size of each row be equal to content.

No, you don't have to. I assume you add text Content for each `ListViewItem` like this:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listView" />
<Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,5" Content="Add Text Item to ListView" Click="Button_Click" />
```

code behind:

```cs
private static string RandomString(int Size)
{
    string input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, Size)
                           .Select(x => input[new Random().Next(0, input.Length)]);
    return new string(chars.ToArray());
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listView.Items.Add(RandomString(new Random().Next(1, 1000)));
}
```

Then it will generate a default `TextBlock` to contain the `Text`:

[image]

Problem is the `TextBlock`'s properties are set to default or Computed value:

[image]

This make all the items has the same size, but the reason is not related to the `ListView` control, if you add text content like this:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Text = RandomString(new Random().Next(1, 500));
    tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    listView.Items.Add(tb);
}
```

Then you can find the difference:

[image]

**Update:**

You can use `DataTemplate` like this:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Collection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ItemText}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

code behind:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Model> Collection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        Collection.Add(new Model { ItemText = RandomString(new Random().Next(100, 500)) });
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
}
```

New rendering image:

[image]

Comment: How do you propose one should do when utilising ListView.ItemTemplate using a DataTemplate?  Cause its a little hassle to create all the DataTemplate values and add it manually right?